# Multiple files compilation error in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, program-entry-point, projects-and-solutions

I tried to compile two source files in Visual studio 2010 (client.c and server.c).

I made a project and kept them in the "source files" folder, but when I run I get the error that `main()` is already defined in other file. When I remove one file (either server.c or client.c) then the other file gets compiled.

I tried a lot to get things right, tried in codeblocks as well, same thing happened.

Comment: It looks like you have two programs (the client and the server), therefore you need to create two projects. You can, however, put them in the same VS workspace (or solution or whatever they name it in the current version).

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that you have two C programs: A Server and A Client, I validly assume that these are expected to run as two different processes (or threads).

- Separate them into two different projects under a workspace (or in different workspaces). You can simply replicate the other dependencies (if there are any) into the newly created project.
- Compile the two projects individually
- Fetch the two executables and run them.

`main()` is an entry-point function hence there should be only one function named `main()` as a program can have only one entry-point. (Yes, there are a few exceptions where you may have multiple instances of `main()`)
And, yes, there are scenarios where there is chance that one or more functions get executed before passing the control to `main()`.
The most likely case and example of that is Microcontroller-based Embedded Systems where you have a Reset Handler and/or a StartUp Handler.

---

### Additional Data (Not really relevent to this question):

In fact, if you try declaring the two functions as shown below,

```
void customDestructor(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));
```

and

```
void customConstructor(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
```

you can add whatever implementation you want before `main()` is executed.

Comment: yeah i had already compiled them making separate projects.thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR** -- One binary (program) can contain one `main()`. Multiple files, each containing `main()` should be treated as seperate *peroject*, not as a single one.

One binary can contain only one `main()`. That is the *point* from which the binary *starts* execution.

If both your source files have `main()` function (which is likely), then you cannot *link* the compiled object files into same binary. You have  to create two seperate binaries. You cannot link two seperate *object files* both having an instance of `main()` defined in them.

I am not very familiarized with VS, but you can look for some options to create two seperate binaries from two different source files, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though are are telling Visual Studio that these two files should be used to compile a single target.  When you tell a compiler this, one and only one of the files in the project *must* have a `main` function.

You need to define two separate targets.  Honestly, I don't use VS for this kind of stuff; I would have used a simple Makefile which would easily allow for two separate targets in the same Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `main` function is allowed.

According to your detail, both `c` files may contain `main` functions. Then your compiler generate an error.